# How to call a static function from Visualforce, which is not in its controller?

Tags: visualforce

I need to use a static helper function in my Visualforce page which will aide in formatting the variables. However, the static helper function is in a helper class, and **not in the controller class**. How can I call this static function?

Comment: Edit: I want to format related records' SOQL fields before displaying them in a `<apex:repeat>` tag in Visualforce. E.g., `{!i.surname__c}`. It is not possible to edit SOQL fields in the controller, unless I create a Wrapper Class. However, owing to the large number of related objects, I do not want to create a Wrapper Class for each object. My question may seem ambiguous/vague so please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Are you looking to utilize dynamic SOQL so that the query is customized based on the sObject?

Comment: @MikeChale, no that is not my requirement. I think I am unable to frame my question properly. I will try to edit it soon. Please feel free to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods are invoked using the class name prefix

Eg FormattingHelper.formatText(arg1, arg2)

If you meant binding it directly to Visualforce then this wouldn't be possible, as only controller variables and methods can be bound
(You can try declaring the containing class as an instance variable of the controller but I don't reckon that works either)

You can invoke the static method from an action method in your controller for eg or in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer! I missed out some details: I want to format related records' SOQL fields before displaying them in a `<apex:repeat>` tag in Visualforce. E.g., `{!i.surname__c}`. It is not possible to edit SOQL fields in the controller, unless I create a Wrapper Class. However, owing to the large number of related objects, I do not want to create a Wrapper Class for each object. My question may seem ambiguous/vague so please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand  'It is not possible to edit SOQL fields in the controller' - you cannot set certain restricted / system fields but otherwise you should be able to set a value on a field of a retrieved record. As long as you don't save the record, the change will only be for the scope of the request. Also you can return formatted values in the getter which is bound to Visualforce by invoking your static helper method.

Comment: Thank you for your time for trying to help. I will delete my question shortly because I am unable frame my question properly. I will find a workaround to my requirements.

Comment: You can let it stay, someone else could interpret it better. Its worth a shot :)